# How to make a table in Xpages that works like Excel

Tags: excel, xpages, xpages-extlib, lotus-notes

I have an excel file with data and need to make this available on web.
The web version of the excel file need to have the following features

- Switch between read and edit mode
- All cells should be editable at the same time
- Inline editing of each cell
- Save all cells that have been changed with a single button.
- Ability to add and remove rows
- Store values in notes document(s)

I have looked at the Dojo Grid JSON REST control in the extension library sample database and it does basically all that I want but I am not happy with the presentation and it seem a bit limited as I later on may need to add other actions to the table cells.

I am looking for an html table version

Which controls should I use to accomplish this? and how can I create a submit button that saves all cells/rows?

Thanks for helping out

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

There is also a project on OpenNTF that gives you a full fledged spreadsheet, that can even load Excel files. It is based on the OpenSource [ZK-Spreadsheet](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkspreadsheet)

[Have a look](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=ZK%20Spreadsheet%20for%20XPages)!

The OpenNTF project was one of the winners in the first OpenNTF contest.

Answer (score 2):

All of those options are possible with the EXTJS grid

You can see some examples here

http://demo.xomino.com/xomino/extjs.nsf

or on the blog

http://xomino.com/extjs

but also check out the examples on the sencha page

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/